# Line Breaks in SharePoint List JSON Formatting in Body (using children?)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I'm trying to add line breaks within the different sections of JSON formatting for my SharePoint list.  Right now, I have sections each with specific fields, however those fields need to have line breaks after certain ones (almost like "sub-sections.").

Is it possible to accomplish this by nesting children `div` elements within sections that have corresponding fields within each?

Here is the code I currently have that results in line breaks, with generic section and field names used for ease of reference:

```
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "",
            "fields": [
                "Title",
                "Field 2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Section 1",
            "fields": [
                "Field 3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Section 2",
            "fields": [
                "Field 4",
                "Field 5"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, adding line breaks or sub-sections is *not possible* using SharePoint JSON form formatting capabilities in body section.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

Body configuration does not support advance JSON customizations like header/footer (or column/view formatting in list views). So, you cannot achieve your requirements using SharePoint JSON form formatting - body layout. You can find more details & limitations in below Microsoft official documentation:

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

Comment: Thank you for the info!  This is really helpful and I can figure out a work-around.